# How to preview and delete images in Krajee bootstrap?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Here is the setting of the initialize the file input. I have successfully done upload file but i want to edit than i cant preview images in the container of krajee bootstrap input. Please if anyone know give the full code to delete and preview.

```
 $("#userfiles").fileinput({
              'dropZoneEnabled': true,
              'maxFileCount': totalcount,
              'showUpload': false,
              'browseLabel': "Click Here or Drag & Drop Images Here",
              'browseIcon': "<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-picture\"></i> ",
              'validateInitialCount': true,
              'allowedFileExtensions': ["jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg"],
              'showCaption': true,
              'showPreview': true,
              'showRemove': true
 }); 

 //This is the ajax for get images from database

 $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: site_url+'posting/getpicdata',
data: {pid: url},
dataType: "json",
success: function(response)
    {
      //console.log(response);
      //var result = JSON.parse(response);

    $.each(response, function(k, v) {
      //display the key and value pair
      //console.log(v.url);
      image_html = v.imgname;
    appendHTML +='<div data-template="image" data-fileindex="0" id="'+v.imgname+'" class="file-preview-frame krajee-default  file-preview-initial file-sortable kv-preview-thumb">';
        appendHTML +='<div class="kv-file-content">';
        appendHTML +='<img style="width:auto;height:160px;"" alt="'+v.imgname+'" title="'+v.imgname+'" class="kv-preview-data file-preview-image" src="'+v.url+'">';
        appendHTML +='</div>';
        appendHTML +='<div class="file-thumbnail-footer">';
        appendHTML +='<div title="'+v.imgname+'" class="file-footer-caption">'+v.imgname+' <br></div>';
        appendHTML +='<div class="file-thumb-progress hide">';
        appendHTML +='<div class="progress">';
        appendHTML +='<div style="width:0%;" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="0" role="progressbar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active">0%</div>';
        appendHTML +='</div>';
        appendHTML +='</div>';
        appendHTML +='<div class="file-actions">';
        appendHTML +='<div class="file-footer-buttons">';
        appendHTML +='<button title="Remove file" data-id="'+v.imgname+'" class="kv-file-remove btn btn-xs btn-default" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-danger"></i></button>';
        appendHTML +='</div>';
        appendHTML +='<div title="Not uploaded yet" class="file-upload-indicator"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-down text-warning"></i></div>';
        appendHTML +='<div class="clearfix"></div>';
        appendHTML +='</div>';
        appendHTML +='</div>';
        appendHTML +='</div>';


  });
```

Comment: please try to rephrase your question, point out where you experience an error, describe it with error message, behavior, etc. You cannot just dump some code, ask `please gimme the codez` and think someone will write it for you.

Comment: you write `appendHTML +=` without defining `appendHTML` in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not totally clear what you are looking for, but I think it's something like this...

```
 <!-- PREVIEW DATA -->
<!-- load the JS files in the right order -->
<!-- sortable plugin for sorting/rearranging initial preview -->
<script src="/path/to/js/plugins/sortable.min.js"></script>
<!-- purify plugin for safe rendering HTML content in preview -->
<script src="/path/to/js/plugins/purify.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/js/fileinput.js"></script>

<script>
$("#userfiles").fileinput({
          'dropZoneEnabled': true,
          'maxFileCount': totalcount,
          'showUpload': false,
          'browseLabel': "Click Here or Drag & Drop Images Here",
          'browseIcon': "<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-picture\"></i> ",
          'validateInitialCount': true,
          'allowedFileExtensions': ["jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg"],
          'showCaption': true,
          'showPreview': true,
          'showRemove': true,
    uploadUrl: "/file-upload-batch/1",
    uploadAsync: false,
    minFileCount: 2,
    maxFileCount: 5,
    overwriteInitial: false,
    initialPreviewAsData: true, // identify if you are sending preview data only and not the raw markup
    initialPreviewFileType: 'image' // image is the default and can be overridden in initialPreviewConfig. see the docs (http://plugins.krajee.com/file-preview-management-demo)
}).on('filesorted', function(e, params) {
    console.log('File sorted params', params);
}).on('fileuploaded', function(e, params) {
    console.log('File uploaded params', params);
});
</script>
```